# What material is the smoothest for air to travel over the wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner

Wings are pretty smooth these days and air travels over the wing easier, so what is the smoothest material

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about this question at all. What is the smoothest material? What material has the least skin friction (from airflow)? Those are two synonymous questions I could think of. If something about them or the OP is unclear, then at the very least a comment asking a specific question should be in order.

Comment: @DrZ214 This seems unanswerably broad to me. Is the question referring to the most smooth material ever used in a wing (which is almost certainly classified and/or proprietary and has as much to do with manufacturing process as with the material itself) or is it asking for the most smooth material ever fabricated (which may suffer the previous drawbacks in addition to almost certainly having other properties that make it unsuitable for aviation?)

Comment: @DrZ214 Engineers almost never ask "What material/device maximizes property x?" but rather "What material/device is good enough across all properties to get the job done and minimizes cost/benefit ratio?" Exotic materials and manufacturing processes are typically reserved for situations that actually require the properties of those materials, not because they have the maximum value for property x.

Comment: @reirab I don't see anything that broad. Both of your rephrasings are answerable, so it's certainly not "unanswerably broad". I'm sure I can find plenty of "beginner questions" on this site where the answerer took time to explain a few possibilities and answered each one.

Comment: @reirab Regarding your 2nd comment, I think you're just wishing for a different question or wishing that the OP was an engineer as opposed to just curious. "What is the smoothest material?" is a perfectly valid and clear question as far as I can tell, and does have relevance in aviation. Just because it's not all an engineer needs to know, doesn't make it bad, and certainly doesn't make it too broad. If anything it would be too narrow.

Comment: @DrZ214 In the present state, it is, at best, unclear which of those questions the OP was asking, if either of them. However, I would still argue that either of those questions is likely unanswerable for the reasons I already mentioned (i.e. answer to the former is probably not public knowledge and answer to the latter might not be public knowledge and is, at any rate, almost certainly not something used in aviation.)

Comment: @reirab I still cannot make much sense of your reasonings. Classified knowledge doesn't affect the question's relevance. You can add on "that we know of" to almost any question and it would be effectively the same. Whether or not the material can be used on aircraft does not affect the aviation relevance of the question. We would need to answer the question first, and even if an answer turned out to be "no, we can't do that" does not mean the question was irrelevant in the engineering process or aviation considerations...

Comment: ...Voretaq7 did a not so bad job of answering this and it's not even that long (the pictures make it look longer). Let's not expect beginners to expound upon multiple possible engineering possibilities. That would almost be like answering your own question in the OP itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first let's dispel the rumor that wings are "pretty smooth" - ideally (in the dreams of aircraft designers and the mathematical perfection of fluid dynamics modeling) they would be, and they certainly are from a distance, but when you get up close and personal most aircraft wings are ugly, bumpy things (as you'll see below). Modern composite wings are a notable exception to this general rule, but there are a few other exceptions in the history of aircraft design.

---

The *material* is, for the most part, not relevant: We usually paint aircraft, so the smoothness of the underlying material contributes less to the surface than the paint preparation, clear coat, and wax.

What does matter are the *construction techniques* used. A few examples (in rough order of decreasing smoothness):

- A modern composite wing can have an almost completely smooth surface (with no rivets or seams in the airflow) - for example a 787 wing, or this SR-20 wing:
  [image: Cirrus SR-20 Composite Wing]
- Some aluminum designs use "bonded construction" (glue) with fewer disruptions of the wing surface. One example are the Grumman AA-1 and AA-5 series aircraft, which has a smooth wing except for the fuel caps and contoured seam lines:
  [image: Grumman Tiger Bonded Wing]
- Conventional aluminum wings can be assembled with flush rivets, which once primed and painted give a very smooth surface with only slight irregularities around each rivet:
  [image: RV-14 flush-riveted wing]
  (Please ignore the blue protective film, and open rivet holes. This is from [an RV-14 under construction](http://rv-14a.blogspot.com/2013/07/wings-fuel-tank-stiffeners-riveting.html) & was the best photo I could find.)
- Fabric wings - one of the oldest wing coverings - are actually pretty smooth. They have "rib stitching" to attach them to the substructure, and are stretched taught over the frame (using heat & dope to shrink the fabric), but the overall result is a very smooth surface between the ribs, with some irregularity over them from the stitches:
  [image: Fabric Wing with stitching]
- Typical aluminum aircraft wing is attached with typical rivets - the head of which protrudes into the airflow slightly. You can see some rivet (and screw) shadows in this image:
  [image: Conventional aluminum wing rivets]

---

Note that I've only considered the ***TOP surface*** of the wing (where airflow and smoothness is most critical). The underside of a wing usually has many other things sticking out into the airflow (fuel tank vents, access/inspection panels, hinges & tracks for control surfaces, etc.) which are a much greater disturbance to the airflow than whatever fasteners are attaching the skin to the rest of the structure of the aircraft.